# Magento ver 2.0.8 -JS texts is not translating in front-end

Tags: php, zend-framework, translation, magento2

In Js:

```
$.mage.__('text to translate')
```

In `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme_name>/i18n/fr_FR.csv`

```
"text to translate","text to translate in french"
```

This is translating in `phtml` but this is not translating if we use this text in js.

Kindly guide me the steps to resolve this.

Comment: Have you read the Magento documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code :

```
require([
'jquery', // jquery Library
'jquery/ui', // Jquery UI Library
'mage/translate' // Magento text translate (Validation message translte as per language)
], function($){ 
    $(window).load(function() {
        alert($.mage.__('text to translate'));
    });
});
```

After that you need to do below things :

- Check your js is loading and you have installed translation package
  too.
- Clear your cache by running cache:clean command
- Run  setup:static-content:deploy to deploy the js again

Comment: app\design\frontend\Theme\main\i18n\fr_FR.csv 
 require([
'jquery', // jquery Library
'jquery/ui', // Jquery UI Library
'mage/translate' // Magento text translate (Validation message translte as per language)
], function($){ 
    $(window).load(function() {
        alert($.mage.__('Type in or select a city to discover'));
    });
});
 This "Type in or select a city to discover" is not translating .I did php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy fr_FR,php bin/magento indexer:reindex,php bin/magento cache:clean,php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: @shaan so whats the issue ?

Comment: Hi Manthan Dave , phtml texts is translating from these csv.But I am having issue with js translation. no errors in console also

Comment: js-translation.json inside the pub/static folder is empty  []

Comment: <?php
$_data = array(
    'Type in or select a city to discover' => __('Type in or select a city to discover'),
);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery", "mage/translate"], 
    function ($) {
        $.mage.translate.add(<?php echo Zend_Json::encode($_data) ?>)
    });
</script> is working

Answer (score 1):

This is a Magento 2 bug.

The workaround is to remove `js-translation.json` and run php `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy <locale>`. This should populate the file and make JS/KO translations work.

You may also want to change file permissions on `js-translation.json` to prevent Magento from overwriting it again with `[]`.

Source: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2056#issuecomment-259641599